# PineScript - Adding to counter in IF statement

Tags: pine-script, counter

I am grabbing a session range (highest high and lowest low) and during a given period I want to see if that highest high or lowest low is exceeded and if so add +1 to a counter. I only want to add +1 to the counter once per session.

Only one event should be recorded per session, either we cross the session high or we cross the session low. Once we cross the session high or low we add +1 to a counter and await the next session.

I am then trying to display the counters value on a table

```
var int ConfirmedSession = na // establish global variable - if na table displays NaN, if 0 table displays 0, doesn't seem to update with counter


Confirmed = false
Confirmed := nz(Confirmed[1], false)
isLong = false
isLong := nz(isLong[1], false)
isShort = false
isShort := nz(isShort[1], false)

if (leaveSession) // if we leave session reset variables back to false
    isLong := false
    isShort := false
    Confirmed := false

// determine long crossover if we are in session
xover = (inSession) and not (isLong) and (close > sessionhigh) and not (Confirmed)

// determine short crossover if we are in session
xunder = (inSession) and not (isShort) and (close < sessionlow) and not (Confirmed) 


if (xover)   // if long crossover then adjust variables
    isLong := true   // the 3 bools all adjust correctly
    isShort := false
    Confirmed := true
    ConfirmedSession := ConfirmedSession + 1    // no matter how I configure this the counter doesn't seem to adjust

if (xunder)  // if short crossover then adjust variables
    isLong := false    // the 3 bools all adjust correctly
    isShort := true
    Confirmed := true
    ConfirmedSession := ConfirmedSession + 1    // no matter how I configure this the counter doesn't seem to adjust


// if xover or xunder then plot shape. Works correctly, only triggers once per session as intended
// so I know that the event is occurring once per session and a shape is plotted when that event happens
// not sure why the counter doesn't seem to adjust accordingly
plotshape(xover, style=shape.circle, location=location.abovebar, color=color.new(color.green, 0), size=size.tiny, display = display.pane)

plotshape(xunder, style=shape.circle, location=location.belowbar, color=color.new(color.red  , 0), size=size.tiny, display = display.pane)

//trying to output the counter value to a table, output is always 0 or NaN
//values inputted manually display correctly 
table.cell(tb, 1, 5, str.tostring(ConfirmedSession, format.mintick), text_color = color.white, text_size = table_size)
```

I've tried many different configurations of trying to add to the counter. The bools all adjust properly. Not sure what I am missing with the counter. I've also tried

```
ConfirmedSession + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning of your code :

```
ConfirmedSession := nz(ConfirmedSession[1], 0) // establish variables
```

will systematically put your ConfirmedSession to 0.

You should only begin your code with (do not use ':=' but '='):

```
ConfirmedSession = 0
```

Then in your 'if' blocks modify this variable this way :

```
ConfirmedSession := 1
```

This way, the ConfirmedSession will be 1 as soon as the (xover) or (xunder) block is passed, and stay to this value.

Comment: I have given this a try and the table still displays ConfirmedSession as 0. Also, for each time xover or xunder is true I want to add +1 to the counter, so it should count hundreds of occurrences

Comment: if you already delete 'ConfirmedSession := nz(ConfirmedSession[1], 0) // establish variables', something else is resetting your ConfirmedSession value. Can you edit your question and paste the complete code ?

Comment: Made a small edit to ConfirmedSession. I've tried 'int var ConfirmedSession = 0' and the table just displays 0. Not sure why it isn't updating in the if (xover/xunder) statements. 'ConfirmedSession' is only mentioned at the top of the script 'var int ConfirmedSession = 0 (or na)' and then again is mentioned in the if (xover/xunder) statements. So not sure how it would be reset

Comment: I've tried adding a simple 'for i=1 to 10, ConfirmedSession := ConfirmedSession + 1' and it doesn't update on the table

Comment: I changed the name of the variable 'ConfirmedSession' and now it counts. Don't know how to explain it, but I'll take it. If you have any idea why that may have fixed things please let me know.

Comment: @PineScrap it would be interesting that your answer your question with your new code, so that we can see the working code.

Answer (score 0):

All I did to get the script working was rename 'ConfirmedSession' to 'number'
var int number = 0 (i've tried 0 with the previous variable name and it would only display 0, now for some reason it updates the way I had intended)

everything else in the code remained the same.